# How run a C# query?

Tags: c#, mysql, select

I use Visual Studio community 2015 and i use MySQL connector (MySQL for Visual Studio) for connection my MySQL database to Visual Studio, this part is already done and i have Visual Studio connected to database.

Now i like to know what is my next step to get (using a select query) data from the database to my form program ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test_1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // How can i get data from the database in here ?
    }
}
}
```

**I got my answer ! Check best answer.**

Comment: This looks like C#/CLI, not C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver My mistake, i mean C# sorry

Comment: I know you meant to type that exact same question into Google first, find something to try, and only ask here if you got stuck on something specific. We're here to help, but you have to help yourself.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger believe me i did ! i can also share the codes i tested ! The problem is as i have no idea how to do it, i don't know where is the problem ! So i just asked how to question !

Comment: Please do - that will let us help you much better.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger Updated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer :

```
MySqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new MySqlConnection("server=server;uid=username;" + "pwd=password;database=database;");
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
MySqlDataReader reader;

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

try
{
 reader.Read();
 value = reader.GetString(x);
}
finally
{
 reader.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've gotta run for a bit so I'll take you at yoyur word that you've tried something and post this in hopes it may help you (it's nice to see what you've done to know how to help you).

You said you had the connection working. Here's some examples of basic queries. The most important thing to remember is there's a lot of different ways to do this, so these are just intended as examples. They are all manual -- for help databinding omething automatically, you'll have to post and ask.

Please PLEASE as you learn to do this - make SURE you always use parameters and don't do things like "UPDATE myUserData set DRIVER_LICENSE = 'U7439821' WHERE LAST_NAME = 'Smith'". You are begging for bad things to happen to you if you do that. Take the extra 30 seconds to use command.Parameter.Add(***,***).

Finally, these examples are for MS-SQL Server. You'll need to change the connection from SqlConnection to MySqlConnection and from SQLCommand to MySqlCommand.

If you have any other questions, just ask.

```
 //these are connection methods that help connect you to your database manually.
 public SqlConnection getConn()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(getConnString());
    }
    public string getConnString()
    {
        return @"Data Source=lily.arvixe.com;Initial Catalog={My_Database_Name};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={My_Database_Username};Password={My_Database_Password};Connection Timeout=7000";
    }

   //to get a single value from a single field:
   public object scalar(string sql)
    {
        object ret;
        using (SqlConnection conn = getConn())
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                com.CommandText = sql;
                ret = com.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            conn.Close();

        }
        return ret;
    }
    //To do a SELECT with multiple rows returned
    private List<string> get_Column_Names(string tableName)
    {
        List<string> ret = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = getConn())
        {
            conn.Open();
            using(SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                com.CommandText = "select column_Name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_Name = '" + tableName + "'";
                com.CommandTimeout = 600;
                SqlDataReader read = com.ExecuteReader();
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    ret.Add(Convert.ToString(read[0]));
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return ret;
    }
    // to do an INSERT or UPDATE or anything that does not return data
    // USE PARAMETERS if people go anywhere near this data
    public void nonQuery(string sql)
    {
        using(SqlConnection conn = getConn())
        {
            conn.Open();
            using(SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                com.CommandText = sql;
                com.CommandTimeout = 5900;
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();

        }

    }
    //to save a DataTable manually:
    public void saveDataTable(string tableName, DataTable table)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = getConn())
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))//, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
            {

                // my DataTable column names match my SQL Column names, so I simply made this loop. However if your column names don't match, just pass in which datatable name matches the SQL column name in Column Mappings
                foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                {
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(col.ColumnName, "[" + col.ColumnName + "]");

                }
                bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 8000;
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                bulkCopy.BatchSize = 10000;
                bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;
                // bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied += BulkCopy_SqlRowsCopied;
                //bulkCopy.NotifyAfter = 10000;
                //isCopyInProgess = true;
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Again, there are more than a few ways to accomplish each of these tasks programatically - I'm just showing you the most basic. If you want to learn how to automatically bind a control to data, try searching for "C-sharp Databind CONTROL_NAME Visual studio" and you should get all the help you need.

Comment: Okay - these should help you. When using a Reader, you'll need to convert the datatype of each field to its intended actual data type (the example I give was for another SO question who only needed strings returned. Also, I did not use any TRY/CATCH/FINALLY to keep things simple, so this will throw an exception if something's wrong. After you figure out the basics, go back and add error handling.

Comment: Thank you, it will take some time for me to figure it out :D but thx :)